# What is this 3ft high, stalky plant, with mid sized narrow leaves?

Tags: identification

Please help me identify this plant.  I live in west-central Maryland.  These guys are growing in a full sun area.  It is about 3' high, stalky, has leafy long, slender, point leaves.  We planted a mixed bag of annual seeds last year in April that were aimed at attracting butterflies, so I'm not sure if I should cut them or leave them. They came up only a couple months ago. Anyone know if these are weeds?

*Click photo for full size*
[image]

Comment: If you know what seed mix you used, you can look up the "ingredient" list, and narrow down possibilities.

Comment: @jmusser, A fair statement, but I don't think either me or my wife will remember what the package looked like.  It was purchased from a nursery, but I doubt we will remember the package name.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: They were supposed to be annuals.

Comment: I think it was April.

Comment: Note, though, these guys weren't here in March, they sprouted about two months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure looks like goldenrod to me considering the leaf structure, dispersion of the leaves, and the fact that it looks like it may have spread from rhizomes

http://joebartok.blogspot.com/2011/09/getting-grip-on-goldenrods.html

They grow well in most parts of Maryland. They are easy to start from scattered seed, and also attract butterflies.  If they did come from your seed packet, they could still be mixed in with annual seeds even if they are perennials.  They could also have easily grown as weeds.

Comment: Also, I have personally seen butterflies most attracted to agastache (licorice mint) out of all the plants planted in the butterfly garden at my nursery. However, that was in the Southwest.

Comment: Holy cow, this does indeed look like it!  Thanks for the id!

Comment: Believe it or not, I had just taken pictures of my goldenrod plants, to post in an answer here! Nice id @user3561.

Answer (score 6):

You may just have to wait for some sort of flower to appear to decide whether you want to keep them or not; I don't know what they are currently, but bear in mind that 'wild flowers' often means 'weeds' in fact. The definition of a weed is a plant growing in the wrong place, but opportunistic weeds are also wild flowers in the sense they grow all by themselves wherever they choose without any human assistance. They may not be ones you want for various reasons, but they are still wild flowers. I'd like to see another pic when a flower does arrive though!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I will certainly be keeping a close eye on them.  I only have one other such spot on my property where I am watching to see what happens, so I will follow up when/if I see a flower.